# Subfolders are not copied through scp command via java

Tags: java, linux

I want to copy all contents of a remote folder ( Windows ) into a local folder ( Linux ) :

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sshpass -p 'devaits@2019' scp 'devaits@app018ait:E:/Oxalys/RECETTE/*' /usr/Axian-Oxalys/xml/working/");
```

The directory "working" has `rwx` privileges for the root user proprietary.

The `RECETTE` folder contains subdirectories `Oxadata/EXPORT`. But at runtime the "working" directory is empty ! So why are the subfolders not copied ( created ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need `-r` option:
`scp -r 'devaits@app018ait:E:/Oxalys/RECETTE/*' /usr/Axian-Oxalys/xml/working/`

Answer (score 1):

`scp` copies recursively only when the `-r` option is specified: [man scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).